# Is there a Fences alternative for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, fences

I like Fences (a program that helps you sort icons on the desktop with icon areas) on Windows, is there another application like it that i can use on my mac computer?

Comment: +1 for the app, my mom will love it :] Don't know about the Mac version though, sorry.

Comment: I've also installed Fences on every family member's computer :)

Comment: You might get more and better answers if you tell the dedicated mac users out there *what* Fences does.

Comment: And add a link for it :)

Comment: I think this is it: http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add spacers to the dock to separate groups of icons from others, just use this terminal comman: `defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{ "tile-type" = "spacer-tile"; }'
killall Dock`

It will create an empty spacer that you can then drag around the dock to group your icons together.

[image]

Using spacers and stacks (folders on your dock) are probably your best bet for replicating fences. You can drop some of the folders from your home dir onto the dock like downloads and documents and if you have rules for pushing certain files into those directories (downloads path from your browser etc.) then those files will always be available there.

[image]

Comment: This is probably my best bet although i'm gonna check out that other answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

I also like Fences for Windows. The closest Mac app that I have found is Dragthing http://dragthing.com/. Dragthing is not exactly the same animal as Fences but in many ways it's much more powerful. I can not live without DragThing on my Mac.

I tried BumpTop on my Mac and I hated it. Bumptop's entire premise is really quite silly. I use my computer to help organize my life not to replicate the mess of papers on my real desktop.

Comment: unfortunately, this isn’t available for macOS versions after 10.14

Answer (score 2):

[Desktop Groups Lite](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/desktop-groups-lite/id561422617?mt=12) is the closest thing available. If you get the paid version you can add further customizations such as background colors and not showing the app icon in the dock.

Answer (score 0):

[AlternativeTo.net](http://alternativeto.net/desktop/fences/?platform=mac) suggests [BumpTop](http://bumptop.com/) as an alternative to Fences.

I haven't used either application myself, but I would expect that the kinds of problems that Fences is designed to solve aren't quite the same on Windows as on the Mac.

Good luck finding something!

Comment: Don't let the description on AlternativeTo fool you. BumpTop is not available for OS X.

Comment: I just figured that out, it looks cool and im probably going to try it on my windows pc but sadly i have to give a -1 here...

Comment: Ah yeah, I'll probably just delete this answer then, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find much options for desktop organization in mac. One is my favorite Dockspaces. Allows you to have multiple Docs and it also works with multiple spaces. I have tried drag thing. There are other better options than drag thing. You can also create alias for different apps and drag it to your dock or You can create a folder in your Application folder and move application based on category and move that folder to your dock.

For Windows Do try Rocket Dock Its Awesome and virtual box(runs Multiple Operating System without any need to restart).

Comment: Next time, try actually answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the app [Desktop Organiser](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/desktop-organiser/id449062537?mt=12) previously. It's available in the Mac AppStore.

It's not as powerful as fences but it will organise files. It does not support "Folder Portals" for example.